# Sticky Mantaflow fluid simulation

Tags: fluid-simulation

New fluid simulation in recent Blender versions (Mantaflow) does not have any setting for interaction with the obstacles.
In result, any fluids, no matter of viscosity, slips right off the surface of an obstacle and it looks quite unnatural.
I'm looking for a way to imitate fluid stickiness.
I've been experimenting with force fields, but so far haven't got any decent results.
Anyone got any ideas?